# How to retrieve a value from outside of JS function

Tags: javascript, function, geolocation

I have been struggling with Google's geolocation API.
I have a function that brings an alert message with city name:

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function Test(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                    for (var b = 0; b < results[0].address_components[i].types.length; b++) {
                        if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "locality") {
                            city = results[0].address_components[i];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                alert(city.short_name)
            }
        } 
    });
```

I would like to retrieve `city.short_name` to use it as a string later. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to set it as a global variable. Or call a function from this function and pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to pass that variable in a function that I created outside and it works. It might be messy of course, but it's not that important.

Comment: It's actually not that messy. You avoid setting up a global variable, which is a good thing !

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind polluting the global variable space, you can use:

```
window.newVar = city.short_name
```

Comment: Mm, I tried to do that, but the console still complains that `newVar` is not defined when I access it outside of the function.